# Luatex and unicode math without unicode-math

Tags: fonts, luatex

I'm using fontspec in lualatex to get a OTF main font, but I'd like to use one of the good old math fonts (like the default TeX one). After trying different packages, I didn't manage to make it work with utf-8 input:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\begin{document}
Test for $\alpha$ and $α$.
\end{document}
```

This renders only the first math symbol correctly. What do I miss exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must declare the alpha. E.g. in `fontmath.ltx` the command `\alpha` is set up this way:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathord}{letters}{"0B}
```

You need the same declaration for the alpha (the `^^^^03b1` are only ascii substitutes for the alpha, you can replace them):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\DeclareMathSymbol{^^^^03b1}{\mathord}{letters}{"0B}
\begin{document}
Test for $\alpha$ and $^^^^03b1$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok. Is there any package that include these definitions for the most common symbols?

Comment: I don't know such a package.

Comment: Ok thank you! Maybe I'll make mine :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez In case you did, would you mind publishing it?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, Did you make yours? :) or find an alternative (within `pdflatex`). It would be very useful.

Answer (score 7):

use the Latin Modern Math font:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{unicode-math,fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{lmmath-regular.otf}
\begin{document}
Test for $\alpha$ and $α$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Hebert, So `fontspec` or `unicode-math}` needs `xelatex` or `lualatex`. Once you use one of them, the document compiles and generates the expected output, even with the the two lines `\setmainfont{...` lines. It even works without the `fontspec` package. (in TeXLive 2012 at least)

Comment: @alfC: sure it loads Latin Modern by default but I wanted to use Pagella!